# How to automatically mark new mail as read in 2 of 3 inboxes in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have three POP3 accounts set up in Outlook (2 old emails, and 1 new email that the old ones forward to the new one).

How do I have new messages in the 2 old email inboxes be automatically marked as read, but keep the new messages in the other inbox stay unread?

Answer (score 2):

Create an Outlook rule (for each old email account):

1. Apply this rule after the message arrives
2. through the *specified* account
3. and on this computer only
4. mark it as read.